# kindly guide me where i am wrong?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, datetime

i have a database where daily sale is recorded.
now i want to get the client outstanding between two dates.
my date_ column is in varchar.
i m not getting the required result.through this query and when i used between query its showing wrong data.so what is the solution? kindly help

```
SELECT clientid AS [ID],SUM(convert(float, total)) AS [SUM] 
       FROM buffalo_milk_sale 
       WHERE clientid BETWEEN 'HD001' AND 'HD099' 
       AND CONVERT(DateTime, date_, 103) >= CONVERT(DateTime, '01/09/2014', 103) 
       AND CONVERT(DateTime, date_, 103) <= CONVERT(DateTime, '09/09/2014', 103)
GROUP BY clientid
```

**Error**

The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Why are you using varchar for a DateTime value ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT clientid AS [ID],SUM(convert(float, total)) AS [SUM] 
FROM buffalo_milk_sale 
WHERE clientid BETWEEN 'HD001' AND 'HD099' 
AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date_, 111) >= CONVERT(DateTime, '01/09/2014', 103) 
AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date_, 111) <= CONVERT(DateTime, '09/09/2014', 103)
GROUP BY clientid
```